# LWP::UserAgent - HTTP::Request

Tags: perl, http-request, lwp-useragent

If I do this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua->get( 'http://www.perl.org' );
```

I can call `HTTP::Response` methods like this

```
say $res->code;
```

Is it somehow possible to call `HTTP::Request` methods from the `$res` object or needs that the creation of a `HTTP::Request` object explicitly?

---

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $method;

my $res = $ua->get( 'http://www.perl.org' );

$ua->add_handler( request_prepare => sub { my( $request, $ua, $h ) = @_; $method = $request->method; },  );

say $method; # Use of uninitialized value $method in say
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HTTP::Request` is used internally by `LWP::UserAgent` and if they would return it via `get` or `post`-Methods it would already be too late since the request is already done. But they have apparently foreseen the need for accessing the request object so they implemented callbacks so you can modify the request before it is sent:

```
$ua->add_handler(request_prepare => sub {
    my($request, $ua, $h) = @_;

    # $request is a HTPP::Request
    $request->header("X-Reason" => "just checkin");
});
```

So if you need to access the request-object without creating it and setting it up - callbacks are the way to go.

Comment: Why does my added example not work as I expected (printing the request method)?

Comment: You have to call `add_handler` before any `get` or `post`-method. In your example the handler is added after `get` and thus not called.

Answer (score 5):

To get the request object that was created for you:

```
my $response = $ua->get('http://www.example.com/');
my $request = ($response->redirects, $response)[0]->request;
```

Might be easier just to create a request object yourself

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( GET );
my $request = GET('http://www.example.com/');
my $response = $ua->request($request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Which `HTTP::Request` methods do you want to call? And on which request object? The last request made by `$ua`?

As far as I can tell, `LWP::get` does not save the last request created/sent anywhere.

Comment: It gets saved in the response object. See my answer.